# PowerShell open Internet Explorer and connect to Website with Credentials

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, credentials

Is it possible to create a PowerShell Script that opens Internet Explorer, and connect to an internal IIS Website with credentials?

First part is easy:

```
$ie = New-Object -Com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate("http://mysite")
```

Now I have no idea how to solve the second part. IE starts and security popup comes up.

[image]

Anyone an idea how to handover the credentials? Thanks in advance.

PS: It's an internal IIS Server. I can choose from Basic or Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If integrated Auth is helpful, how about using Start-Process with the -Credential parameter.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -ArgumentList "http://mysite" -Credential $YourCreds
```

Or you wrap that to get the correct folder if this will be running on different computers.

```
if ($arch = $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -eq 'AMD64') {
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -ArgumentList "http://mysite" -Credential $YourCreds
}
else {
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -ArgumentList "http://mysite" -Credential $YourCreds
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP is looking to authenticate via PowerShell.